# (plesk)After adding 1000 youtube url to my 1000 different wordpress article, my all websites doesnt show yt url as embed

Tags: php, posts, embed, youtube

i added 1000 article with 1000 youtube url, i directly pasted youtube url, but after that, including that site, my all sites on my dedicated hosting doesnt show the youtube embed after i paste direct url, normally it would automaticly turn to embed when i direct paste url, but now its not. its no problem for previously published articles but it occurs when i try to add new one. its plesk problem (some kind of spam embed block) or something different?i t was thinking if youtube banned my ip but my dedicated includes 5 different ip so all my websites has same problem, i think its something with plesk but i am not sure.

This error occurred again 4 months ago and it resolved itself a week later.